# python compare subsection of 2 strings and see if they match

Tags: python

I have 2 strings e.g.

```
str1 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1'
```

and

```
str2 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1.1'
```

I want to compare the text which comes after 'section1.1:' and return whether it is the same or not.  In the example it would return false as the first says `section 1` and the second says `section 1.1`

The first piece of the string can be anything e.g. subsection2.5: but always ends with a `:`

What is the best way to do this using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [split method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) of the strings to split on only the first `:`:

```
>>> str1 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1'
>>> str2 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1.1'
>>> str1.split(':', 1)[1]
'  this is a heading for section 1'
>>> str2.split(':', 1)[1]
'  this is a heading for section 1.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  They don't always start with the same text, just in my example. I'll give your solution a try

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how well you know what the format will be, you might do something like this.

```
In [1]: str1 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1'
In [2]: str2 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1.1'
In [3]: if str1.split(":", 1)[1] == str2.split(":", 1)[1]: 
   ...:     print "true"


In [4]: str2 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1'

In [7]: if str1.split(":", 1)[1] == str2.split(":", 1)[1]:
   ...:     print "true"


   true
```

You can always strip the responses if you're concerned about trailing or leading whitespace to be different.

(edit: Missing line in IPython session)

Answer (score 0):

You can translate this pretty directly into code:

```
def compare( str1, str2):
   # I want to compare the text which comes after the first ':' (for example)
   def find_that_part( s ):
       idx = s.find(':') # where is the first ':'?
       return s[idx:] # the part after it

   # and return whether it is the same or not.
   return find_that_part(str1) == find_that_part(str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split(":")` solutions in the other answers work fine. If you already parsed the first part (before the colon) in some way, and you know the length, you could do a simple string comparison like this:

```
parsedUntilColon = "section1.1:" # for example

if str1[len(parsedUntilColon):] == str2[len(parsedUntilColon):]:
    print "strings are equal"
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner should be cool!!

```
>>> str1 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1'
>>> str2 = 'section1.1:  this is a heading for section 1.1'
>>> cmp = lambda str1, str2: [x_.findall(str1) == x_.findall(str2) for x_ in [re.compile(':[\w*\s*\.*]*')]][0] and True
>>> cmp(str1, str2)
False
```